# How can I get input via file without opening and closing the file in C?

Tags: c

I want to get input from a file in C without opening and closing it, like with use of `fscanf` or `fgets`. I just want to redirect my stdin to a file.

Comment: Then invoke `cat file.txt | ./myprog` and read from `stdin` in your program.

Comment: ... or `./myprog < file.txt`

Comment: So I should use normal scanf just the way I use for keyboard and just do the redirection

Comment: Yes! Use scanf like you normally would for user input. You can also redirect output (like printf) to a file.

Comment: I also would like to know , how does reading from a file with just redirecting it to file . does it take elements from data file in an order of scanf and how does it identify spaces

Comment: The file contents are just input as if they were entered by the keyboard and can be read with scanf. Does that answer your question? Could you clarify what you are asking?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use redirection from the command line:

```
yourprogram < input_file
```

Use scanf as you normally would for keyboard input. Redirection is nice because you can get input from a file or the keyboard with the same program (if you don't use redirection, input will come from the keyboard).

Also, you can redirect output to a file:

```
yourprogram > output_file
```

Or both:

```
yourprogram < input_file > output_file
```